# How to a third-party module uses a layout update that changes the template path for a core block?

Tags: magento2.3.0

A third-party module uses a layout update that changes the template path for a core block from  Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml toMyCompany_MyModule::custom/view/addto/compare.phtml. The merchant has a customized version of this template in their custom theme. What is a consequence of this setup?

```
A - This setup will throw an IllegalStateException.

B - If a preference for the core block is set, the template will no longer apply.

C - If another module is installed which also customizes the same core template, the templates will be rendered sequentially.

D - If the custom module is removed, the custom template will no longer apply.
```

Please correct me on this which answer is correct of given 4 options
i tried much R&D of it and according to C or D is the correct answer please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

## Correct answer is **D**.

Ref: [Magento DevDocs Override templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates)

Answer (score 1):

I think not **A**: If a template cannot be found, as far as I know, the block is just not rendered.

Also probably not **B**: A preference on the block only leads to some weird behavior, it the theme path does not contain the Module prefix. For example if the theme path is declared as only `custom/view/addto/compare.phtml`, the Module part of the theme path is determined by the Namespace of the block. In this case, adding a preference to a block that changes the `\Company\Module\` namespace would lead to the theme being loaded from `Company_Module::custom/view/addto/compare.phtml`

**C** (slightly different): If another module sets the template, it depends on the module loading order which one will be used. If not defined explicitly via module sequence (in `/etc/module.xml` of the module) I think it's determined alphabetically, where the module is used, that comes last in that order (see `app/etc/config.php` for the actual module loading order in your project).

And definitely **D**: If the module is removed (and no other module changes the path to the theme) it will be loaded from `Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml` again.

Comment: so which one is correct

Comment: that depends on your specific case, your description is very general. Based on the information you provided partly C and definitely D

Answer (score 0):

Simple **Answer is D.**

D - If the custom module is removed, the custom template will no longer apply.